# Reflection exception in Route.php in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I got a reflection exception in Route.php in laravel.The message was

"Method App\Http\Controllers\PagesController::getContact() does not exist "

Here is my PagesController

```
        <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller
{



 public function getIndex (){

  return view("welcome");

 }

 public function getAbout(){

    return view("pages.about");

 }

 public function getContact(){

 return view("pages.contact");

}

}
```

And here is my route php file

```
    Route::get('/', [
'as' => '/', 
'uses' => 'PagesController@getIndex'
]);

Route::get('about', [
  'as' => 'about', 
  'uses' => 'PagesController@getAbout'
 ]);


  Route::get('contact', [
    'as' => 'contact', 
    'uses' => 'PagesController@getContact'
  ]);
```

i cant find the reason behind it.

Comment: Did you do a composer update or composer dump-autoload

Comment: No. How can i do that.will you explain please.thanks for your comment.

Comment: From your commanline cd to your priject root, then run composer update. You should have composer installed by now I guess.

Comment: thank you very much.it worked